# Regex to find consecutive IP Addresses

Tags: python, regex

I finally have to throw in the towel after working with this for quite some time today. I am trying to retrieve all the IP addresses from a output that looks like this:

```
My Address: 10.10.10.1
  Explicit Route: 192.168.238.90 192.168.252.209 192.168.252.241 192.168.192.209
                  192.168.192.223
  Record   Route:
```

I need to pull all the IP addresses between from 'Explicit Route' and 'Record  Route'. I am using textfsm and I seem not to be able to get everything I need.

Comment: Are the values after "Explicit Route:" always IP addresses separated by spaces?

Comment: can't you use standard string functions like `split()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex and string operations:

```
import re
s = '''My Address: 10.10.10.1
  Explicit Route: 192.168.238.90 192.168.252.209 192.168.252.241 192.168.192.209
                  192.168.192.223
  Record   Route:'''
ips = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', s[s.find('Explicit Route'):s.find('Record   Route')])
```

Comment: `ips = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d{1,3}', s[s.find('Explicit Route'):s.find('Record   Route')]) `     Had to add the quantifier after the digit for the last octet. Other than that this worked perfectly!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    f = file.read().splitlines()
    for line in f:
        found = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})', line)
        for f in found:
            print(f)
```

Edit:

We open the txt and read by line, then for each line using regular exp. to find the ips ( can have 1-3 numbers, then . and repeat 4 times)

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is usually better to provide some explanation so that others will get the most out of your answer in the future.